# How can I assign "coursecreator" role to a user in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I write a plugin in moodle that should assign "coursecreator" role to some users.

```
$coursecreatorroleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', array('shortname' => 'coursecreator'));

role_assign($coursecreatorroleid, $user->id,context_course::instance());

if (user_has_role_assignment($user->id, $coursecreatorroleid))
    echo "True";
```

But it does't work. Can anybody help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a course context instance, without giving a course id.

So, you should write:

```
$context = context_course::instance($courseid);
role_assign($coursecreatorroleid, $user->id, $context);
```

Alternatively, if you want to assign the role at the site level, or at a category level (which makes sense for the course creator role), you should use context_system::instance() or context_coursecat::instance($catid).

If also advise you to turn on debugging (if not already on) - http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging - as that will give you helpful error messages and warnings.

Comment: `context_system::instance()` was my answer. Tnx a lot.